# What happens when the Brush in a DC Motor touches two commutators

Tags: dc-motor

I was watching this video and realized that there is a point in time when the brushes positive and negative can be shorted as shown in the image below. And it made me curious.

For people with experience or understanding of dc motors, what exactly happens at that point in time when this short happens?

[image]

Comment: Nobody ever does a two-segment commutator or there would be a short-circuit. The minimum you will ever see is 3 segments in which case the short circuit is not across the supply but a coil that already has close to zero voltage across it.

Comment: Actual motors use at least 3 armature poles. This avoids the problem of shorting them out.

See this answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452876/why-doesnt-a-commutator-cause-the-rotation-to-reverse-periodically-or-stop/452878#452878

Comment: Although your specific concern is a non-issue due to motor design, your concern does arise in a slightly different form. You might find this interesting: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/492161/why-is-it-an-advantage-that-carbon-brushes-have-high-resistance